Must one never ask about mtgox's outages?
mtgox.com has been down for about an hour.  Last time I posted a question about this, my question and my credibility were disparaged:
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8855/why-is-mtgox-down
Is it forbidden ever to ask about this, even those it's covered in the news media?

Your question was closed as being too localized. A good rule of thumb for detirmining whether a question is too localized is to ask yourself, "Who would be interested in this question in 6 months?"
In this case, the interested parties would be limited to people who are designing exchanges.
Let me also make a counterexample: Suppose you ask a question about the March 2013 blockchain fork. This was also a temporary problem, but because it affects so many more people, the number of people interested is correspondingly higher.

Is it forbidden ever to ask about this, even those it's covered in the news media?

Whether it's covered in news media is irrelevant, because news media is about current events. The StackExchange formula is really bad at covering current events. There are lots of things that StackExchange doesn't do well; we respond by not doing them. (see #2, don't build a truck)
Also, the fact that you padded out your question probably didn't help.

The problem is mostly that the question was poorly phrased so that it only applied to a single point in time. For example, if the question was more like, "What caused the significant Mt. Gox outage on March 30, 2013" rather than "mtgox.com has been down for maybe three hours" it likely would have fared better.
